# How to fix Nokogiri on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, xml, ubuntu, nokogiri

I run Ubuntu 13.04 on my workstation with ruby 2.0.0, which was installed via RVM.

$ aptitude show libxml2

`Package: libxml2

State: installed
Automatically instlled: no
Multi-Arch: same
Version: 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.1`

$ aptitude show libxml2-dev

`Package: libxml2-dev

State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Multi-Arch: same
Version: 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.1`

$ aptitude show libxslt-dev

`Package: libxslt1-dev

State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 1.1.27-1ubuntu2
Priority: optional`

$ nokogiri -v

`WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
 # Nokogiri (1.6.0)
    ---
    warnings:
    - Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
    nokogiri: 1.6.0
    ruby:
      version: 2.0.0
      platform: x86_64-linux
      description: ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-linux]
      engine: ruby
    libxml:
      binding: extension
      source: packaged
      libxml2_path: /home/pb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2/2.8.0
      libxslt_path: /home/pb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt/1.1.26
      compiled: 2.9.0
      loaded: 2.8.0`

I installed nokogiri with the command, because else it's using libxml2 version 2.8.0, but I'm not sure where it takes this from, since just libxml2 is installed via apt.

`gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2/libxml --with-xslt-dir=/usr/include/libxslt`

When I run my application I get the following error:

`/home/pb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in require': /home/pb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2/2.8.0/lib/libxml2.so.2: versionLIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by /home/pb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/libxml-ruby-2.6.0/lib/libxml_ruby.so) - /home/pb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/libxml-ruby-2.6.0/lib/libxml_ruby.so (LoadError)`

Can anyone tell me how I get rid of libxml2 version 2.8.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Nokogiri is using its own version of `libxml` by default. Probably because Mac OS provides a version of libxml that is dated 2001 (!), and old libraries don't provide features Nokogiri depends on. However, this may cause a problem with the systems that are kept up-to-date. To resolve the problem you need to build Nokogiri against the libraries your OS provides.

This maybe something like this, it's from Arch Linux:

```
gem install nokogiri -- \
  --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2/libxml \
  --with-xml2-lib=/usr/lib \
  --with-xslt-include=/usr/include/libxslt \
  --with-xslt-lib=/usr/lib
```

You may need to install development packages if using distros like Ubuntu or Fedora. It should be `libxml2-dev` and `libxslt1-dev` on Ubuntu but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I had a similar issue with libxml-ruby being compiled against the system libxml2, and nokogiri being compiled against its vendored libxml2, then trying to require both in the same Ruby process.  Your command worked on Debian, but I had to use `--with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2` (removed trailing `libxml`).

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, this is the only thing that worked for me on 14.04

```
gem uninstall nokogiri
NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install # or use gem install instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran across your question researching an issue of my own. It looks like, for a time, the nokogiri team was overriding the system install of libxml at gem install time as indicated in this comment: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/829#issuecomment-16877522. Not sure if that helps you, but it seems relevant. Perhaps a new version of Nokogiri is in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall it with system library.

`gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.5 -- --use-system-libraries`