# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler" trying to run a cloned repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I cloned a repo repository for a project in Ruby, but I couldn't run it whatsoever, when I run `rails s`  I get the following error.

```
[DEPRECATED] Your Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more than once without a block is security risk, and may result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicatwhich gems should come from the secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config setisable_multisource true`.
The git source `git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data withoutncryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config set git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` procol to keep your data secure.
The git source `git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encrtion. Disable this warning with `bundle config set git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocoto keep your data secure.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails was resolved to 3.2.2, which depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.1.4)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 1.0)', which is required by gem 'rails', in any of the sources.
```

Ofcourse, I tried installing the ruby & rails versions that the project was built on, that didn't work either.

this is my Gemfile

```
require 'rbconfig'
HOST_OS = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
source "http://rubygems.org"
#source "http://gemcutter.org"
source "http://gems.github.com"
gem 'rails'
gem 'mysql2'

group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", "2.0.3"
    gem "client_side_validations"
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.8.0.rc1", :group => [:development, :test]

group :test do
    gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.4.0"
    gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.2.0"
    gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.2"
    gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.7.0"
    gem "launchy", ">= 2.0.5"
    gem "mocha"
end

group :development do
    # case HOST_OS
    #   when /darwin/i
    #     gem 'rb-fsevent'
    #     gem 'growl'
    #   when /linux/i
    #     gem 'libnotify'
    #     gem 'rb-inotify'
    #   when /mswin|windows/i
    #     gem 'rb-fchange'
    #     gem 'win32console'
    #     gem 'rb-notifu'
    # end
    #gem "guard", ">= 0.6.2"
    #gem "guard-bundler", ">= 2.1.4"
    #gem "guard-rails", ">= 0.0.3"
    #gem "guard-livereload", ">= 0.3.0"
    gem "guard-rspec", ">= 0.4.3"
    #gem "guard-cucumber", ">= 0.6.1"
    gem "rails-footnotes", ">= 3.7"
    gem "nifty-generators"
    gem "letter_opener"
    gem "capistrano"
end

gem "devise", ">= 1.5.0"
gem "has_scope"
gem "simple_form"
gem "nested_form", :git => 'git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'
gem "cancan", :git => "git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git", :branch => "2.0"
gem "paperclip", '2.4.5'
gem "delayed_job_active_record"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0"
gem "squeel"
gem "tire"
# gem 'elastic_searchable'
# gem 'rd_searchlogic', :require => 'searchlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic.git'
gem "ransack"#, :git => "git://github.com/ernie/ransack.git"
gem "ancestry"
gem "private_pub"
gem "thin"
gem "delayed_paperclip"
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'therubyracer', :group => :production
gem "business_time"
```

and when I run `bundle install` I get the following error

```
Fetching source index from http://gems.github.com/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://gems.github.com/

Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://gems.github.com/

Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://gems.github.com/

Could not fetch specs from http://gems.github.com/
```

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (default: 1.4.1)
bundler (default: 2.1.4, 1.0.22)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
csv (default: 3.0.9)
date (default: 2.0.0)
did_you_mean (1.3.0)
e2mmap (default: 0.1.0)
etc (default: 1.0.1)
executable-hooks (1.6.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.1.0)
forwardable (default: 1.2.0)
gdbm (default: 2.0.0)
gem-wrappers (1.4.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.7)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.0.0)
json (default: 2.1.0)
logger (default: 1.3.0)
matrix (default: 0.1.0)
minitest (5.11.3)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
net-telnet (0.2.0)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
ostruct (default: 0.1.0)
power_assert (1.1.3)
prime (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.1.0)
rake (12.3.2)
rdoc (default: 6.1.0)
rexml (default: 3.1.9)
rss (default: 0.2.7)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
shell (default: 0.7)
stringio (default: 0.0.2)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
sync (default: 0.5.0)
test-unit (3.2.9)
thwait (default: 0.1.0)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

This is my Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git
  revision: c94de4ab1805d2e080ebd658051c59d0ec5147ce
  branch: 2.0
  specs:
    cancan (2.0.0.alpha)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git
  revision: 486e0f0e93f3ca455d5d0fc7869053257b6afce2
  specs:
    nested_form (0.2.0)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  remote: http://gemcutter.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      mail (~> 2.4.0)
    actionpack (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activemodel (3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
    activesupport (3.2.2)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.7)
    ancestry (1.2.5)
      activerecord (>= 2.2.2)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    business_time (0.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.0.0)
    capistrano (2.11.2)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.3.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    client_side_validations (3.1.4)
    cocaine (0.2.1)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    commonjs (0.2.4)
    cookiejar (0.3.0)
    cucumber (1.1.9)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
      gherkin (~> 2.9.0)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
      term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.6)
    cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.1.8)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
    daemons (1.1.8)
    database_cleaner (0.7.1)
    delayed_job (3.0.1)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
    delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2)
      activerecord (> 2.1.0)
      delayed_job (~> 3.0.0)
    delayed_paperclip (2.4.5.1)
      paperclip (>= 2.4.5)
    devise (2.0.4)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.1.1)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    em-http-request (0.3.0)
      addressable (>= 2.0.0)
      escape_utils
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
    em-websocket (0.3.6)
      addressable (>= 2.1.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    escape_utils (0.2.4)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    exception_notification (2.5.2)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)
    execjs (1.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (2.6.4)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.9)
    factory_girl_rails (1.7.0)
      factory_girl (~> 2.6.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faye (0.8.1)
      cookiejar (>= 0.3.0)
      em-http-request (>= 0.3.0)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
      faye-websocket (>= 0.4.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      yajl-ruby (>= 1.0.0)
    faye-websocket (0.4.4)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
    ffi (1.0.11)
    gherkin (2.9.1)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    guard (1.0.1)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    guard-bundler (0.1.3)
      bundler (>= 2.1.4)
      guard (>= 0.2.2)
    guard-cucumber (0.7.5)
      cucumber (>= 0.10)
      guard (>= 0.8.3)
    guard-livereload (0.4.2)
      em-websocket (>= 0.2.0)
      guard (>= 0.10.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    guard-rails (0.1.0)
      guard (>= 0.2.2)
    guard-rspec (0.6.0)
      guard (>= 0.10.0)
    has_scope (0.5.1)
    highline (1.6.11)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    journey (1.0.3)
    jquery-rails (2.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.5)
    launchy (2.0.5)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    less (2.0.11)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.0)
      therubyracer (~> 0.9.9)
    less-rails (2.1.8)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less (~> 2.0.7)
    letter_opener (0.0.2)
      launchy
    libv8 (3.3.10.4)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    metaclass (0.0.1)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    mocha (0.10.5)
      metaclass (~> 0.0.1)
    multi_json (1.1.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    net-scp (1.0.4)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    net-sftp (2.0.5)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.9)
    net-ssh (2.3.0)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    nifty-generators (0.4.6)
    nokogiri (1.5.2)
    orm_adapter (0.0.6)
    paperclip (2.4.5)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.2)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    private_pub (1.0.1)
      faye
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.2)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      activerecord (= 3.2.2)
      activeresource (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      bundler (~> 2.1.4)
      railties (= 3.2.2)
    rails-footnotes (3.7.5)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    railties (3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    ransack (0.6.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.9.0.rc2)
      rspec-core (= 2.9.0.rc2)
      rspec-expectations (= 2.9.0.rc2)
      rspec-mocks (= 2.9.0.rc2)
    rspec-core (2.9.0.rc2)
    rspec-expectations (2.9.0.rc2)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.9.0.rc2)
    rspec-rails (2.9.0.rc2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec (= 2.9.0.rc2)
    rubyzip (0.9.6.1)
    sass (3.1.15)
    sass-rails (3.2.4)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    selenium-webdriver (2.20.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
    simple_form (2.0.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    sprockets (2.1.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    squeel (0.9.5)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
    therubyracer (0.9.10)
      libv8 (~> 3.3.10)
    thin (1.3.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    tire (0.3.12)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rake
      rest-client (~> 1.6.0)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.0.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less-rails (~> 2.1.6)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.32)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.1.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.3)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    yajl-ruby (1.1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  ancestry
  business_time
  cancan!
  capistrano
  capybara (>= 1.1.2)
  client_side_validations
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  cucumber-rails (>= 1.2.0)
  database_cleaner (>= 0.7.0)
  delayed_job_active_record
  delayed_paperclip
  devise (>= 1.5.0)
  exception_notification
  factory_girl_rails (>= 1.4.0)
  guard (>= 0.6.2)
  guard-bundler (>= 0.1.3)
  guard-cucumber (>= 0.6.1)
  guard-livereload (>= 0.3.0)
  guard-rails (>= 0.0.3)
  guard-rspec (>= 0.4.3)
  has_scope
  jquery-rails
  launchy (>= 2.0.5)
  letter_opener
  mocha
  mysql2
  nested_form!
  nifty-generators
  paperclip (= 2.4.5)
  private_pub
  rails (= 6.0.3.2)
  rails-footnotes (>= 3.7)
  ransack
  rspec-rails (>= 2.8.0.rc1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  simple_form
  squeel
  therubyracer
  thin
  tire
  twitter-bootstrap-rails (= 2.0.3)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  will_paginate (~> 3.0)
```

I just feel like I've come to a dead end. any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of rails do you require? The ruby and rails versions arent mentioned. If you update your gemfile with those, bundler will be able to do a much better job

Comment: I assume this is a very old rails project? The Gemfile.lock probably holds the actual versions and this also requires a specific version of bundler. Try uninstalling your bundler 2 version and install an old bundler 1 version with `gem install bundler -v`

Comment: I tried ```gem install bundler -v '~>1.0.0' ``` and it got me the 1.0.22 version for some reason

Comment: @MoizMansur My current rails version is 6.0.3.2 and when I try to run ```rails -v``` in the project directory gets me the same error mentioned above. My ruby version is 2.6.3p62

Comment: Are you using RVM or anything to create a gemset per project - or all of your gems “globally” installed on your machine?

Comment: @TomHarvey I am using RVM to manage running different projects at different Ruby versions only. but No, I am not using gemsets, I just run ```gem install``` for any gem I want to install

Answer (score 3):

Create a clean gemset for the project with `rvm gemset use myOldRailsProject --create`

Then `gem install bundler -v '~>1.0.0'`

Run `gem list` to check what gems you have installed and which versions. If there is a newer bundler; remove it. And, post the output of this command to your answer so we can see what gems you have in your gemset. While you’re at it, also add the contents of Gemfile.lock

Remove the line `source "http://gems.github.com"` from your Gemfile

Finally, in your project directory (you can do the above commands from anywhere on your machine) run `bundle`

Comment: gems seemed to install after I ran `bundle` I got this error `An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.2 --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before
bundling.`

Comment: Progress! This is kind of a different problem. Probably already answered on here somewhere. Which OS are you installing onto?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: You now have this problem (standing up old versions is going to be tricky) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468910/how-to-fix-nokogiri-on-ubuntu. Try `apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev` and then `NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install`